# Make one node subelement of another

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I am trying to add the `<Item>` block within the `<Items>` parent block. To get, for example:

```
<Items>
    <Item>...data...</Item>
    <Item>...data...</Item>
    <Item>...data...</Item>
</Items>
```

Here is what I have thus far:

```
>>> from lxml.etree import Element
>>> items=Element('Items')
>>> item=Element('Item')
```

How would I add the item underneath the items? What I've tried to do is:

```
>>> SubElement(items, item)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2935, in lxml.etree.SubElement (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:67070)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 175, in lxml.etree._makeSubElement (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:15221)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1498, in lxml.etree._getNsTag (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:27720)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1516, in lxml.etree.__getNsTag (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:27870)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1393, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:26460)
TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got '_Element'
```

Comment: @Selcuk -- that's it. thank you. You can leave that as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.append()` method of the [`Element` class](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-element-class):

```
>>> from lxml.etree import Element, tostring
>>> items = Element('Items')
>>> item = Element('Item')
>>> item.text = "foo"
>>> items.append(item)
>>> print(tostring(items, pretty_print=True))
<Items>
  <Item>foo</Item>
</Items>
```